# Connect an Android device to a web app that is open in my desktop browser

Tags: android, web, bluetooth, communication

I've been looking all over the place to try to figure out a way to send information from a web page that is open on my desktop browser to an Android device.  I am trying to do this because the web page is like a code interpreter and I want to send the written code from the web page an Android app that I am working on. So the web page is like an IDE and the Android app is also an IDE but I'm making the web app to make typing easier and the user can just send the code to the Android app from the web page.

I could not get the web Bluetooth to see my android device Nokia 6 [web Bluetooth example](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/device-info.html?allDevices=true), web sockets do not seem like the right way to do it. Maybe there is a way to connect through local IP address?

Also there cannot be any communication with a server. it has to be from web page client directly to the android device.

I'm not too sure on how to go about this, any advice is greatly appreciated thank you for your time